# jQuery Advance Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<ul id="comment1">
 <li>reply1</li>
 <li>reply2</li>
 <li>reply3</li>
 <li>reply4</li>
 <li>reply5</li>
 <li>reply6</li>
 <li>reply7</li>
 <li>reply8</li>
</ul>
```

how to select last 3 or 4 replies with jquery?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A common selector in similar cases is `$('li:gt(4)')`, to select all replies except the first 5: http://jsfiddle.net/CMY52/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

To get last four items (updated with -4 as suggested by @KennyTM):

```
$('ul#comment1 li').slice(-4).css('color', '#00ff00');
```

Comment: Use `.slice(-4)` to select the last 4 replies.

Comment: @KennyTM: Although I have updated my answer but count for your comments keeps on increasing, interesting :)

Comment: It’s probably because `$('ul#comment1 li').slice(1, 4)` is plain wrong. That would get just the second, third and fourth element.

Comment: @Gumbo: Yeah right i have removed that quite some time ago though realizing it could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#comment1 li:last-child')
     .prev('li').andSelf()
     .prev('li').andSelf()
     .prev('li').andSelf()
     .prev('li').andSelf()
```

Should get the last four

Comment: and then again, there's slice(-4).  Which is a much better method IMO